# Correct use of streamz with websocket

Tags: websocket, tornado, streamz

I am trying to figure out a correct way of processing streaming data using `streamz`. My streaming data is loaded using `websocket-client`, after which I do this:

```py
# open a stream and push updates into the stream
stream = Stream()

# establish a connection
ws = create_connection("ws://localhost:8765")

# get continuous updates
from tornado import gen
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

async def f():
    while True:
        await gen.sleep(0.001)
        data = ws.recv()
        stream.emit(data)
        
IOLoop.current().add_callback(f)
```

While this works, I find that my stream is not able to keep pace with the streaming data (so the data I see in the stream is several seconds behind the streaming data, which is both high volume and high frequency). I tried setting the `gen.sleep(0.001)` to a smaller value (removing it completely halts the jupyter lab), but the problem remains.

Is this a correct way of connecting streamz with streaming data using websocket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `websocket-client` provides an async API and, so, it's blocking the event loop.

You should use an async websocket client, such as the one [Tornado provides](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html#client-side-support):

```python
from tornado.websocket import websocket_connect

ws = websocket_connect("ws://localhost:8765")

async def f():
    while True:
        data = await ws.read_message()

        if data is None:
            break
        else:
            await stream.emit(data)

        # considering you're receiving data from a localhost
        # socket, it will be really fast, and the `await` 
        # statement above won't pause the while-loop for 
        # enough time for the event loop to have chance to 
        # run other things.
        # Therefore, sleep for a small time to suspend the 
        # while-loop.

        await gen.sleep(0.0001)
```

You don't need to sleep if you're receiving/sending data from/to a remote connection which will be slow enough to suspend the while loop at `await` statements.

Comment: Thank you very much, just to clarify on your comment about `sleep`, this is only an issue for running it inside `jupyter lab`, right? If I were to run this in a stand-alone script where nothing else is happening, then there are no other events in the loop, so sleep wouldn't be needed?